# A RenderFlex overflowed by 99889 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, dart

i am getting an error like this

Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99889 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    GridTileBar

And here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import '../providers/products.dart';
import '../providers/cart.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String id;
  // final String title;
  // final String imageUrl;

  // ProductItem(this.id, this.title, this.imageUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
              arguments: product.id,
            );
          },
          child: Image.network(
            product.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              onPressed: () {
                product.toggleFavoritestatus();
              },
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            product.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              cart.addItem(
                product.id,
                product.title,
                product.price,
              );
              Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text(
                    'Added item to cart!',
                  ),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'UNDO',
                    onPressed: () {
                      cart.removeSingleItem(product.id);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please help!

And also one error is also showing like this

Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Consumer

Comment: Overflow error can be easily fixed most of the time by wrapping overflow causing Widget tree in SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: i have done that also but nothing happened. Still showing the same error.

Comment: Please do post snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code snippet, gridtilebar is not able to render the widgets as there is a conditional logic written below.

Please check if below condition(product.isFavorite) returns null or has a valid boolean value.

```
product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
```